# Error ts7016 when trying to use JS modules from npm with vue.js

Tags: npm, vue.js

When I try to use *vu-currency-filter*, I get this error

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-currency-filter'. 'C:/dev/budgetManagement/node_modules/vue-currency-filter/dist/VueCurrencyFilter.bundle.js'

Is there a workaround for this?
I've tried a couple of the currency filters on *npm* and they all seem to have this problem. Should I abandon *TypeScript* and just use *JavaScript*?

I've read things online for other people having this problem, but they all seem very confusing.

I am using the vue.js template put out by Microsoft and VisualStudio.